# adding hero-unit class using bootstrap makes the div not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im new at bootstrap and im trying to make my first page using bootstrap but when i added the `class="hero-unit"` to the `div` it makes it not responsive (it is responsive without it).

as you can see in the picture

[image]

and here is my code:

```
    <div class="container pagination-centered">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="hero-unit">

                <h1>Bootstrap search</h1>
                <p><br/><br/></p>


                <div class="input-append">              
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search ...">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i have seen [Bootstrap responsive: How to fix a non-responsive element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885799/bootstrap-responsive-how-to-fix-a-non-responsive-element) and [Bootstrap - forcing alignment of responsive elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200640/bootstrap-forcing-alignment-of-responsive-elements) but it didnt help me .

any help would be apreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version are you using? If I'm not mistaking, hero-unit is in a far past in version history of Bootstrap. take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron, I think what you are trying to make is a so called jumbotron, which is utilized 100% responsive already.

Comment: i found that im using 2.3.2 , i will try to use jumbotron and let u know, but it should be working tho because as u can see here on this website he used hero-unit http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/hero.html

Comment: well using jumbotron solved it , but its destroyed all of my work :D,
i will have to start all over again with the new bootstrap. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're handy with css you could also try to make a responsive util with media queries for the hero-unit yourself. But still recommend to work with the new, it offers a lot more, also more stable!